# How to do two-by-two column comparison thanks to the column name on an R datframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, stat

I have a dataset with different columns and I would like to compare a column with its replicate. I have two replicates for each sample. The name of replica 1 is of this type: `name_sample_1` and of replica 2: `name_sample_1_2`.

I would like to compare replicate 1 and replicate 2 for each sample: if a value is present in one replicate and in the other it is 0, I would like to replace the two values ​​by `NA`.

Original

| replicate_1 | replicate_1_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 750 | 0 |
| 0 | 850 |
| 650 | 950 |

Wanted

| replicate_1 | replicate_1_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| NAN | NAN |
| NAN | NAN |
| 650 | 950 |

here is a screenshot of my header

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that extends to n pairs of columns with the same prefix.

First, use reproducible data. There are two pairs of columns with the same prefix:

```r
dat <- structure(list(some_name_replicate_1 = c(0L, 750L, 0L, 650L), 
    some_name_replicate_1_2 = c(0L, 0L, 850L, 950L), some_othername_replicate_1 = c(0L, 
    750L, 0L, 0L), some_othername_replicate_1_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    950L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

#   some_name_replicate_1 some_name_replicate_1_2 some_othername_replicate_1 some_othername_replicate_1_2
# 1                     0                       0                          0                            0
# 2                   750                       0                        750                            0
# 3                     0                     850                          0                            0
# 4                   650                     950                          0                          950
```

The code consists of:

1. Split the columns according to their prefix and create a list
2. Replace the necessary values to NAs
3. Reduce the list to the original dataframe format

```r
dat |>
  split.default(gsub("_replicate_1.*", "", colnames(dat))) |>
  lapply(function(x) {
    x[x[1] * x[2] == 0 & x[1] + x[2] != 0, ] <- NA
    x
  }) |>
  Reduce(f = cbind)

# some_name_replicate_1 some_name_replicate_1_2 some_othername_replicate_1 some_othername_replicate_1_2
# 1                     0                       0                          0                            0
# 2                    NA                      NA                         NA                           NA
# 3                    NA                      NA                          0                            0
# 4                   650                     950                         NA                           NA
```

Comment: What if I want to average between the remaining values ​​for replicate 1 and a replicate 2.

Comment: You can use rowMeans in the lapply function

Answer (score 1):

You can do this vectorized base R approach with indexing, which isolates all the rows with the given conditions and replaces all values across columns with `NA`:

```
df[(df$replicate_1 == 0 | df$replicate_1_2 == 0) &
     !(df$replicate_1 == 0 & df$replicate_1_2 == 0), ] <- NA
```

Output:

```
#   replicate_1 replicate_1_2
# 1           0             0
# 2          NA            NA
# 3          NA            NA
# 4         650           950

 # Data
df <- read.table(text = "replicate_1    replicate_1_2
0   0
750 0
0   850
650 950", header = TRUE)
```

Note that this replaces values across **all** columns with `NA` - if you only want to replace values with `NA` in certain columns, you can specify them:

Example data building off of what you provided, adding an extra column to ignore (keep values):

```
df2 <- read.table(text = "replicate_1   replicate_1_2 ignore_column
0   0 A
750 0 B
0   850 C
650 950 D", header = TRUE)

df2[(df2$replicate_1 == 0 | df2$replicate_1_2 == 0) &
     !(df2$replicate_1 == 0 & df2$replicate_1_2 == 0), 
     c("replicate_1", "replicate_1_2")] <- NA
```

Output:

```
#   replicate_1 replicate_1_2 ignore_column
# 1           0             0             A
# 2          NA            NA             B
# 3          NA            NA             C
# 4         650           950             D
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for a method where I don't have to specify the exact name of the column because I have a dataframe with 28 columns: 14 for replicate 1 and 14 for replicate 2

Comment: Ok - it's best to edit your question and specify exactly what you want with reproducible data that more accurately represents your situation.